# FontAwesome in the Tabular environment

Tags: tables, fontawesome

I am not able to compile my latex document when I put a fontawesome command in a tabular environment.

This is a snippet for reproducing the error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\title{Test}
\author{lordthistle }
\date{May 2016}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\faicon{\faEnvelope} Test

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\faicon{\faEnvelope} & Test \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The file can be viewed and compiled here:
[sharelatex project](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57271780b3d3dd9b06b54e1c)

Is there any trick to use the `\faicon` command in a tabular env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing `\faicon`: *either* you use `\faicon{<name>}` *or* `\fa<Name>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\title{Test}
\author{lordthistle }
\date{May 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\faEnvelope\ or \faicon{envelope}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\faicon{envelope} & Test \\
\faEnvelope & Test \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg, it was obvious from the documentation, my fault. Strange I do not receive any error when I use `\faicon{\faSomething}' outside of a `tabular` environment.

Comment: @AntonioSesto I do get an error: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faicon{\faEnvelope}
\end{document}`

Comment: Using the latest MikTeX on Windows 10 I do not get any error. On sharelatex (using pdflatex as compiler) I do get an error `\faicon{\faEnvelope}`.